# Total Return of US S&P 500, last 50-years

Tags: data-request, usa, finance

While price data is easily available, total return data is a bit difficult to find free/open sources for. I am not looking for some massive data set that goes back to Galilean times, or covers small caps in tiny economies. I just need last 50 years or so of US S&P 500 or similar large cap stocks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for "Dividend Yield", which can be added to any gains or losses to give the total return.

http://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-dividend-yield/

http://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-dividend-yield/table

For "total return" maybe you mean "earnings yield"

http://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-earnings-yield

http://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-earnings-yield/table/by-year

Comment: Thank you, but Total Return is a very precise term that simulates dividend reinvestment (promptly upon distribution). It looks just like a price series but the calculation requires precision due to the volatility of equity prices.

Answer (score 0):

Robert Shiller has monthly total returns of the S&P 500 going back to 1871 on his website at Yale: [http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm](http://www.econ.yale.edu/%7Eshiller/data.htm)